# Sometimes clicking on notification does not open the dropdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

As simply as the title states, sometimes when I click the red circle with a number to go to my new inbox messages in the StackExchange Dropdown, nothing happens. I've never experienced this before, it's only begun lately and it seems to be happening more and more. What could be wrong?

Edit: [this user](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1140) has the same problem, and he is **also** using FF12, which cannot be a coincidence.

Comment: It looks like you're not alone here: http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1140/refresh-required-to-read-inbox-messages (I haven't seen it happen yet, though)

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I'm on Chrome 19, but I'm not sure if it has something to do with my SE extensions. Clicking `Stack Exchange` instead of the red circle works fine though. (CC @balpha)

Comment: Just tried with all extension (SE and general) disabled. No difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, some shuffling in the inbox code left the click handler for the little number hanging under certain conditions.

Comment: So you shuffled a "notifications" tab in there? Nice! :-)

Comment: That's handy indeed.

Comment: @Arjan - new feature, [notifications tab](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/revamped-notifications/).