# "Multi-Collider Thingy" doesn't dropdown on question pages (IE8)

Tags: bug, stack-exchange-button, internet-explorer-8

*sigh...* I am embarrased to admit that my workplace still has us running on Windows XP with IE8 (and that installing Firefox, Chrome or other non-standard software has the extreme potential of getting you fired), so I'm assuming this "bug" is related to my jalopy of a browser and might not even be worth investigating.

I noticed today that the StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™ will not appear if clicked when viewing a question page. It works just fine on the main page and from my profile (and, if memory serves, worked fine yesterday), but when I visit a question and click on it nothing (that I can see) happens.

(This *might* be related: [Sometimes clicking on notification does not open the dropdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133185/191410))

Comment: FYI, StackExchange supports mainly the latest two major versions of a browser. The full list can be found here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need

Comment: Your TM's are not ™'s! Eeeeeek!

Comment: @animuson - Hmm... that post is a bit grey on IE8. ["*Our realistic minimum browser specification is Internet Explorer 7. The site will work in Internet Explorer 7, but it may not look entirely correct.*"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56192/191410)

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII - fine, if you're going to be picky about it.

Comment: @Cybȫʁgϟ37 That was also originally posted in 2010. I've gone ahead and just edited that paragraph out to avoid confusion. :)

Comment: @animuson - I have no complaints, but you might want to update the FAQ to reflect that IE8 is no longer supported. "Supported: 10 and 9 ... Explicitly unsupported: 7 and earlier ..." (no mention of where IE8 stands, or to what degree it is supported/unsupported.)

Comment: The "Explicitly Unsupported" lines are versions that Stack Exchange has officially said somewhere, in writing, that they *do not* support anymore. Any version between those and the officially supported "2 versions back" are assumed to be unsupported based on the "2 versions back" policy. For example, Firefox's support mentions nothing between 6 and 21.